# How to create modules in a features(outer) module for Dynamic Features with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dynamic-feature-module

[image: Dynamic Feature Module folders]

While checking out this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery/index.html?hl=it#0) i saw that feature modules are inside an outer module called `features`. Is it possible to create such a structure with Android Studio, or is it done by creating a features folder manually and adding those feature modules manually and setting gradle file afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about it can be done by `Android Studio` but the simple way following these steps

1. You create a `Module` as normal from `Righ Click` in `app` folder
2. Create `Directory` with name `features`, switch to `Project` structure view and move your `Module Directory` to `features`
3. If you using `dynamic-feature-module` you have to change in `settings.gradle` file and `build.gradle` app.

Comment: Yes, it's like i thought but using Project structure to move modules makes it one step shorter than i anticipated.

Comment: Haha agree with you, if android studio can support we config path when create module so we no need move module directory manually

Answer (score 3):

you can do this while mentioning module name.

First create a directory

e.g feature in root level

then Create new module

in module name:-   feature:module-name

Comment: there's no need to create a feature directory after creating a module and writing module name {feature:module-name} The IDE will create a feature directory.